# Crud Webapp Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, crud

Is it possible create Crud Webapp with Google Apps Script. I need to create a web table able to update and get values from Google spreadsheet?

Answer (score 5):

yes its possible, you can insert, update a row, delete and retreive a row using google app scripts
try this link https://github.com/AishwaryT/Google-app-script-crud
let me know if you face any problem.

Answer (score 2):

Yes absolutely it is possible. 
 Write a code in Google app script for CRUD operation over the Google spreadsheet (like Insert, Update, delete). accept the parameters using doGet() / doPost() method to insert/update data into the Google spreadsheet and return the updated data or any response in the JSON/XML or in the string format, deploy your app script (with "anyone even anonymous"), copy the URL of the deployed script and call to that URL from your your web application (in java script AJAX call) and get response from app script to your application.

Reference :https://developers.google.com/apps-script/