# Google script to find and update rows in other sheets by unique ID

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have about 4 separate spreadsheets that accepts user input and when the user is finished they push a button to ‘log’ the information on another sheet. All of the spreadsheet entries from user input have a unique ID assigned to them.

What I am trying to do is when the user clicks the button the script searches another sheet for the matching ID and updates Column B to the new value.

Basically like a simple lookup, but instead of returning the value, it updates.

```
Sheet 1                 Sheet 2
    A       B               A       B 
1  ID123 | Received  >   1  ID123 | Ordered
2                        2
```

So as the user changes ID123 in spreadsheet 1 to Received, the button searches for ID123 in spreadsheet 2 and if it exists (it always will), cell b1 in sheet 2 gets updated with the value in B1 in sheet 1.

I did come across another post talking about a [CRUD web app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38014698/crud-webapp-google-app-script), but I am thinking that is a bit more complex than what I am looking to do here!

Thank you for any assistance!

**EDIT:**
The button I mentioned is added in via a custom image in which this script will be assigned to.

It might help to add that the 'Starting sheet' will only ever have 1 ID on it. It is the 'destination sheet' that will have multiple ID's, even the same ID repeating multiple times, in which case all matching IDs would need to be updated.

[Sample of Starting Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YN2RR.png) and 
[Sample of Destination Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iHwx7.png)

As you can see above, in the 'Starting Sheet', ID3 has a Status of "Received". Upon pushing that Submit button, the script would need to find "ID3" in the 'Destination Sheet' and replace whatever text is in the Value column with "Received". So in this example, ID3 is being updated from "Ordered" to "Received".

Comment: Might be worth hyper-linking to the CRUD post.

Comment: Here is the URL. Sorry, I do not know how to link any other way yet (in the app).    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38014698/crud-webapp-google-app-script

Comment: Thanks. You can edit post, click hyperlink button, and paste link. Just thinking having more data/considerations in the question might help get an answer here.

Comment: @DanielSims Thanks! Also added it to original post.

Comment: **accepts user input** - how ? google form or custom dialog inside sheets ? **push a button** - where ? google form or custom menu item or button in a sheet cell ? Need these details.

Comment: @ra89fi By “Accepts User Input” I only mean that the spreadsheet allows the user to update the cell that contains the information I would like update on another sheet. By “Push a button” I mean a custom menu item with a script assigned to it. Sorry if I wasn’t clear in the original post.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if(e.range.getSheet().getName() != 'Sheet1'){return;}
  if(e.range.columnStart==2) {
    var id=e.range.offset(0,-1).getValue();
    var rg=e.source.getSheetByName('Sheet2').getDataRange()
    var vA=rg.getValues();
    for(var i=1;i<vA.length;i++) {
      if(vA[i][0]==id) {
        vA[i][1]=e.value;
        break;
      }
    }    
  }
  rg.setValues(vA);
}
```

Sheet1 and Sheet2:

[image]

You can attach this function to a button as desired:

```
function updateEntrees() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh1=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var rg1a=sh1.getRange(2,1,sh1.getLastRow()-1,1);
  var vA1a=rg1a.getValues();
  var rg1b=sh1.getRange(2,2,sh1.getLastRow()-1,1);
  var vA1b=rg1b.getValues();
  var sh2=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  var rg2a=sh2.getRange(2,1,sh2.getLastRow()-1,1);
  var vA2a=rg2a.getValues();
  var rg2b=sh2.getRange(2,2,sh2.getLastRow()-1,1);
  var vA2b=rg2b.getValues();
  for(var i=0;i<vA1a.length;i++) {
    for(var j=0;j<vA2a.length;j++) {
      if(vA1a[i][0]==vA2a[j][0]) {
        vA2b[j][0]=vA1b[i][0]
      }
    }
  }
  rg2b.setValues(vA2b);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Cooper. This works perfectly set up as a trigger! Ultimately, this does exactly what I needed, but I wonder if it can be modified to only run when the user presses a button that has been inserted on the sheet. The button is an image with a script assigned to it. Example: “Submit”.

Comment: I’ll take a look at that

Answer (score 0):

You can copy/paste below code inside existing button function to copy current cell value to destination sheet cell accordingly after search by id. Check for duplicate variable names though.

```
var acRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveRange();
var val = acRange.getValue();
var row = acRange.getRow();
var col = acRange.getColumn();
var id = acRange
  .getSheet()
  .getRange(row, 1)
  .getValue();
var rg = SpreadsheetApp.getSheetByName('destination sheet name here').getDataRange();
var vA = rg.getValues();
for (var i = 1; i < vA.length; i++) {
  if (vA[i][0] == id) {
    vA[i][col - 1] = val;
    break;
  }
}
rg.setValues(vA);
```

Comment: This also worked well. But I may not be able to depend on the user having the correct cell selected, especially if the user is expected to click in another area for the button. Is there a way to adapt this to search for the ID on the 'Start Sheet' in the 'Destination Sheet'? Adding this to original post, but it might help adding that the Starting sheet will only ever have 1 ID on it. IT is the destination sheet that will have multiple, even the same ID repeating multiple times, in which case all matching IDs would need to be updated.

Comment: User can edit a cell then keeping the cell selected, click a menu item. I see no issues in that. If its an issue nonetheless, onEdit trigger is better. It'll always catch the active cell. Finding ID in 2nd sheet is not a problem, problem is knowing the last immediate update so correct ID and new cell value can be captured.