# Update the a Sheet ID to another sheet based on Status

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I Need to find a solution to update the Google Sheet2 based on Sheet1's status. E.g. If I update the Sheet1 in Column 2 status as "Available", I want to grab the ID of Column 1 and place it in the Sheet2 (but to avoid duplicates if available)

Here is my example work sheet

[image] [image]

I found this code in [Stackoverflow search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55410746/google-script-to-find-and-update-rows-in-other-sheets-by-unique-id) which is much closer to my work expectation but I need  with little changes, I tried to play around but it didn't' work as expected. How can I fix this?

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if(e.range.getSheet().getName() != 'Sheet1'){return;}
  if(e.range.columnStart==2) {
    var id=e.range.offset(0,-1).getValue();
    var rg=e.source.getSheetByName('Sheet2').getDataRange()
    var vA=rg.getValues();
    for(var i=1;i<vA.length;i++) {
      if(vA[i][0]==id) {
        vA[i][1]=e.value;
        break;
      }
    }    
  }
  rg.setValues(vA);
}
```

---

Comment: Do you want to remove the row in sheet1 after it has been moved/copied to sheet2? What if a duplicate id was found? Remove the row anyway? Or should it stay in sheet1 ?

Comment: Not to remove, Just to copy. If duplicate is found, Do not remove but don't copy to Sheet2

Comment: This can be done with a simple formula. Do you really want to have a script?

Comment: Yes, because we have an operation to edit or delete the rows in the Sheet2, Adding formula may get complicate things. So it's better to copy the ID with a script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this script

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName() != 'Sheet1' || e.range.columnStart !== 2 || e.value !== 'AVAILABLE'){return;}
   const rg=e.source.getSheetByName('Sheet2')
    const values = rg.getRange("A:A").getValues().flat().filter(String)
    const id = e.range.offset(0, -1).getValue();
    if (!values.includes(id)) {
      rg.appendRow([id])
    }
}
```

and see if that helps?

Comment: I have small issue to resolve, the data is copied in the Sheet 2 in random rows of Column A than which should copy after the last data in Column A in order. Can you please help me to resolve it? e.g. the current code copies to Column A row number 13, 15, 19 etc... I want this copy in order as 10,11,12,13 continue... i.e. right after the last entry of the row.